# What is a minikube Add-On?

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I've worked through [my first Kubernetes tutorial](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/hello-minikube/).

Near the end, this tutorial introduced the concept of "add-ons" -- for example, you can install the `metrics-server` add-on by running

```
$ minikube addons enable metrics-server
```

What are these add-ons?  Are they a feature that's specifically related to minikube, or can they be used with any kubernetes cluster and `minikube addons` is just some syntactic sugar that points at some shell scripts that can do anything?

Put another way -- what is happening behind the scenes when I run

```
$ minikube addons enable some-add-on
```

Are all add-ons enabled the same way (like, maybe they create a deployment?) -- or will different add-ons be installed in different ways depending on their functionality?

I'm basically trying to understand *how* a programmer could extend kubernetes themselves. When I go looking for documentation on this I find either lists of add-ons [I can use](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/addons/) (which point to add-ons being more than a `minikube` thing), or [very broad documentation on ways to extend kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/) that don't make any mention of "add-ons" by name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What are these add-ons? Are they a feature that's specifically related to minikube

Yes, this is specific to Minikube.

Kubernetes is manly a container orchestrator. It is typically installed in an environment with lots of servers, e.g. a Cloud Provider like AWS or GCP. Kubernetes does not work isolated, it has abstractions and need *real* infrastructure from outside.

Some examples:

- Load Balancer were your app traffic arrives through
- Virtual Machine or Physical Machines to e.g scale out your cluster with more Nodes when you want autoscaling.
- Disk volumes, either local volumes on the node, or storage via a network protocol.

In a cloud environment like e.g. Amazon Web Services, these things would be provided with other AWS services like e.g. [Elastic Load Balancer](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/), [EC2](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) virtual machines or [Elastic Block Storage](https://aws.amazon.com/ebs/). Other providers like e.g. RedHat OpenShift, specialized on Kubernetes for on-prem environments has other ways to provide these resources, e.g. via [VMWare vSphere](https://www.vmware.com/products/vsphere.html)

**Minikube** is specialized for running Kubernetes on your local machine and to allow you use Kubernetes as how it would appear in a environment with many servers, it need to mimic those features, e.g. use your local machine for [Persistent Volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/).

You can see the Minikube add-ons with this command:

```
minikube addons list
```

Comment: Thank you @jonas -- do you happen to know where "the code that runs when you run `minikube addons`" lives so I can see what enabling each add-on actually does? Top of head answers only -- I can probably figure it out by digging into minikube's sources :)

Comment: It seem to be here: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/tree/master/pkg/addons

Comment: also worth investigating: https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/contrib/addons/